# maven issue, remote repository unavailable

Tags: java, maven, repository, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

My project configuration refers to a remote repository, which does not exists, so the project deploys fail.

But the libraries do exist in my local m2 repo.

What do I have to do so that my local repo is used?

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>alfa-repository</id>
            <url>http://some_remotelink/libs
            </url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>alfa-repository</id>
            <url>http://some_remotelink/libs
            </url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
.......
    <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>alfa-repository</id>
    <!--            <url>http://some_remotelink/libs/</url>-->
                            <url>C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<distributionManagement>` and `<repositories>` tags and tag contents and try again. It should get dependencies from local repository.